# Find error in functions (sum, subtract, multiply) with square matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void matrixRandomFill(int size, int size2, int matrix[size][size2]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size2; j++ ) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 9;
        }
    }
}

void matrixSum(int size, int size2, int matrix1[size][size2], int matrix2[size]    [size2], int matrixSum[size][size2]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size2; j++ ) {
            matrixSum[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void matrixSubstract(int size, int size2, int matrix1[size][size2], int matrix2[size]    [size2], int matrixSubstract[size][size2]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size2; j++ ) {
            matrixSubstract[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] - matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void matrixMultiply(int size, int size2, int matrix1[size][size2], int matrix2[size]    [size2], int matrixMultiply[size][size2]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size2; j++ ) {
            matrixMultiply[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void matrixPrint(int size, int size2, int matrix[size][size2]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size2; j++ ) {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    printf("Enter matrix size NxN: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int matrix1[size][size];
    int matrix2[size][size];
    int matrixSum[size][size];
    int matrixSubstract[size][size];
    int matrixMultiply[size][size];

    matrixRandomFill(size, size, matrix1);
    matrixRandomFill(size, size, matrix2);

    printf("Printing first matrix:\n");
    matrixPrint(size, size, matrix1);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Printing second matrix:\n");
    matrixPrint(size, size, matrix2);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Printing matrix1 + matrix2:\n");
    matrixPrint(size, size, matrixSum);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Printing matrix1 - matrix2:\n");
    matrixPrint(size, size, matrixSubstract);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Printing matrix1 * matrix2:\n");
    matrixPrint(size, size, matrixMultiply);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

the functions look normal, but i keep getting something like this:
Printing matrix1 + matrix2:
 0  0  0 
 0  0  0 
 0  0  0

or

Printing matrix1 - matrix2:
-1761243347 32767 -1761341440 
32767  0  0 
 0  0  0

looks like some kind of segmentation fault, but i can't figure out where i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are just printing the matrices but not performing any operations before it.

```
// You forgot to call matrix sum function here.

printf("Printing matrix1 + matrix2:\n");
matrixPrint(size, size, matrixSum);
printf("--------------------------------------\n");
```

Similarly for subtraction, multiplication operations as well.

Comment: Don't worry. It happens once in a while for me as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Your functions matrixSum etc are never called.

Comment: should i call it this way? -     matrixSubstract(size, size, matrix1, matrix2, matrixSum);

Answer (score 1):

As others said, You never actually evaluate matrixSum and the rest, also I found that your local(to main) variables that have the same name as your functions hide your functions, so they will be no longer available past those variable declarations.

The way I see your another problem is(by example):

```
int iwilldosomething(int a, int b) /*function iwilldosomething */

int main(void)
{
  int iwilldosomething;     /* local variable iwilldosomething */
  iwilldosomething(2, 3);    /* here you will get error, because main can see iwilldosomething and will tell that iwilldosomething is not a function */
.
.
.
```

Comment: No, you can't call the function under its name. Because you gave locally the same name to array, your matrixSum is now array, not a function. See?

Comment: Look at the code I added. You will encounter the same thing in a while.